# Getting multiple same answer in matlab - Roots

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I've been working in MATLAB and i noticed something odd when i did run this code. It gives me 5 same answer.

```
syms x;
f = x^4 * sin(x);
assume(x >= -10 & x <= 10);
solve(f,x)
```

It's output is correct
(0
0
0
0
0
pi
-pi
-2*pi
2*pi
-3*pi
3*pi)
But as you can see it gives me 5 zero. I couldn't figure out why.I've tried different conditions that is defined for solve, still getting multiple zero. is it just how it is?

Comment: Perhaps it gives `0` several times because it is a _multiple_ root. In fact, `f = x^5 * sin(x)` produces `0` _six_ times

Comment: Yes, Seems that way. Actually i have asked my teacher about it, He said the same thing.